# nodejs nested queries in a callback

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, nested

I've found many one-to-many relations examples but I've not found a very clear example in solving nested queries for a normalized data in 'mongodb' or it's just me being thick headed. Please help.
I've following models called 'User', 'Account' 'Library'.

```
User: { 
  name: String,
  password: String //Hash of course
}

Library: { 
  name: String,
  address: String
}

Account: { 
  user_id: String,
  library_id: String
}
```

This is because a user has many accounts with various libraries (I can definitely put them embedded in the 'User' document or Library information in the 'Account' document). 
I'm trying to code (see below snippet) to put all the documents together as a one array of JSON objects as shown below, but it's not clear how or where do I return the response as in "res.json(allaccountsdata)" or may be there is a better way?

```
function isLoggedIn() { 
  // this validates the user and puts user object in the req
}

app.get('/account', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  var allaccountsdata = [];
  Account.find({user_id: req.user._id}, function(err, accounts) {
    account.forEach(function(account) {
      Library.find({_id: account.library_id}, function(err, library) {
        account.library = library;
        allaccountsdata.push(account); // Where do I return this???
      });
    }); 
  });
});
```

I know this is not very efficient and not real mongodb way but I'm just trying to understand how do do this if my data is all normalized in a mongodb.

-Atarangp

Comment: I'm assuming you're using this in conjuction with express?

Comment: yes I'm using express.

Answer (score 0):

You can query for multiple items in on query. Construct a list with the library IDs, and use that to find all libraries. Untested example:

```
Account.find({user_id: req.user._id}, function(err, accounts) {
  // Get an array with the library IDs
  var libraryIds = accounts.map(function(account) {
    return account.library_id;
  });
  // Find all relevant libraries in one query
  Library.find({_id: {$in: libraryIds}}, function(err, libraries) {
    // Join the libraries to the accounts
    accounts.forEach(function(account) {
      account.library = libraries.find(function(library) {
        return library.id === account.library_id;
      });
    });
    return res.json(accounts);
  });
});
```

Comment: vesse, I'll and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: vesse, I'm get libraries.find() is undefined function error?

Comment: @Atarang sounds like the response (ie. `libraries`) is not an array since [find() is an Array prototype method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and thus always defined for arrays. Check what the returned libraries looks like and adjust accordingly.